# how to make dry contact with serial reading one time in every state in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I did this code and when button is released open message is in loop but when I press the button the "close" message keep no loop

how can I show "open" message one time not in loop...I mean when button release then the "open" message shows one time?

So when button is release will write "open" in serial , then when push the buton the write "close" in serial.

```
int Switch = 2;

int buttonState;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 1;     // previous state of the button

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Switch, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop()
{
buttonState = digitalRead(Switch);

 if (digitalRead(Switch) == LOW && buttonState == lastButtonState) {
  Serial.println("Open");
  delay(100);


  }

   if (digitalRead(Switch) == HIGH && buttonState != lastButtonState){
     Serial.println("Close");

   }
     lastButtonState = buttonState;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

use a flag instead of lastButtonState!
for example:

```
int flag=0; //global
void loop(){
if(digitalRead(Switch) == LOW && flag==0){
    flag=1;    
}

else if(digitalRead(Switch)==HIGH && flag ==0){

   flag=2;

}


if(flag==1){

  //print whatever you want

  flag=0;

 }

else if(flag==2){
     //print the second case
     flag=0;
 }}
```

Also, it is not a good practice to read the button state like that. Because buttons will be pressed Async to the system and you should denounce them.

```
if(digitalRead(SWITCH)==LOW){
    delay(40);
    if(digitalRead(SWITCH)==LOW)
        changeButtonState();
}
```

Comment: I tried Flag, and gave me boncing loop between "open" and "close" and when press the button gave me "close" in loop!

Answer (score 0):

I got what I want from the code like this:

```
int Switch = 2;  //Pin for sensor switch

int buttonState;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(Switch, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

 }
  void loop()
 {
  buttonState = digitalRead(Switch);

   if (digitalRead(Switch) == HIGH && buttonState != lastButtonState) {

   Serial.println("open");
   delay(180);

 }
   lastButtonState = buttonState;

 if  (digitalRead(Switch) == LOW && buttonState == 1){
  Serial.println("Close");
  delay(200);

  }


 }
```